# Tikzpicture /pfgplots in list of figures:

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents

I'm a beginner with LaTeX and i have insert graph, with a csv file and pfgplots
But how can i have the title of the graph in the list of figures.
Thank you

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    title={$U=E-R\cdot I$ représentation graphique},
    no markers,
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=12, ymax=14,
    ]
\draw[<->,thin] (axis cs:9, 12.5625) -- (axis cs:9, 13);
\draw[<->,thin] (axis cs:0, 13.125) -- (axis cs:9, 13.125);
\node at (axis cs:9.5,12.784){$\Delta U$};
\node [above] at (axis cs:4.5,13.125){$\Delta I$};
\draw [-,semithick,red] (axis cs:0, 13) -- (axis cs:10, 13);
\draw [<-,semithick] (axis cs: 4,12.8) -- (axis cs:4,12.75);
\draw [->,semithick] (axis cs: 4,12.75) -- (axis cs:5,12.75);
\node [below] at (axis cs:4.5,12.75){$\dfrac{dU(I)}{dI}=-R$};
\addplot table [x=I, y=U, col sep=comma] {test.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I guess that what you need is described [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)

Comment: Your document doesn't see inside your TikZ picture. You need to place it inside a figure environment and put a `\caption`

Comment: Oh thank you didnt see this wikipedia page, i've found the other for chemical and electrical equation.
Will try thank you Jules

Comment: Note, you can use \captionof{figure} (caption package) outside a figure environment.  BTW, the list of figures is really a list of (figure) captions.